# WooCommerce - My account Page add anchor link to the REGISTER section

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I'm trying instead of splitting the WooCommerce My Account page into a separate Login and Register pages, to have an anchor link placed in from of the title REGISTER above of the register form for example `<a href="#register"></a> REGISTER`

That way I could have a Sign Up link straight to this section in mobile.

I found this function to replace the title "Register" for anything you want. But it won't render the html:

```
function register_text( $translated ) {
    $translated = str_ireplace('Register',  '<a href="#register"></a> REGISTER',  $translated);
    return $translated;
}

add_filter(  'gettext',  'register_text'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'register_text'  );
```

See how it looks: https://pasteboard.co/JLk3GBS.png

Any thoughts?

FYI: I'm using Flatsome theme.

Comment: Instead, [**override**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) Woocommerce related template file: [`myaccount/form-login.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.9.1/templates/myaccount/form-login.php) via your child theme and edit it… It will better work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the text of this section is replaced with `esc_html`.

You can easily do this using the `wp_is_mobile` function and the `woocommerce_login_form_end` hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end', 'ywp_add_register_anchor_text' );
function ywp_add_register_anchor_text() {
    if( ! wp_is_mobile() ) {
        return;
    }
    echo '<a href="#register"></a>';
}
```

You can also use the woocommerce template editing method.

Code goes in the functions.php file of your active theme/child theme. Tested and works.

Comment: Worked flawlessly Hamid! Thank you so much!